# How to workaround git add -i --patch being limited to one split?

Tags: git

When adding patches interactively in `git` with `git add -i --patch` one has the option to split a patch into smaller pieces. These pieces sometimes are very large and there's no option to split again. Afaik editing is the only option.

How can I make `git` add only everything under `//test rest/user/randomofferincognito without authentication` in the following example:

```
@@ -1500,13 +1532,35 @@
                 OfferRest.PATH,
                 OfferRest.UNREVIEWED_OFFERS_COUNT_METHOD))).openConnection();
-        uc1.setRequestProperty("Accept", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
-        if(200 != uc1.getResponseCode()) {
-            Assert.fail(String.format("response code was %d and response text '%s'",
-                        uc1.getResponseCode(),
-                        IOUtils.toString(uc1.getErrorStream(),
-                                Charsets.UTF_8)));
-        }
-        restResponse = IOUtils.toString(uc1.getInputStream(),
+        uc2.setRequestProperty("Accept", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
+        SeleniumHelper.assertResponseCodeEquals(Response.SC_OK,
+                uc2);
+        restResponse = IOUtils.toString(uc2.getInputStream(),
+                Charsets.UTF_8);
+        Assert.assertEquals("0",
+                restResponse);
+        //test rest/offer/reviewalloffers
+
+        //test rest/user/randomofferincognito without authentication
+        final HttpURLConnection uc3 = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(generateURL(String.format("rest/%s/%s",
+                OfferDevRest.PATH,
+                OfferDevRest.RANDOM_OFFER_INCOGNITO_METHOD))).openConnection();
+        uc3.setRequestProperty("Accept", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
+        SeleniumHelper.assertResponseCodeEquals(Response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
+                uc3);
+        //test rest/user/randomofferincognito with authentication
+        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
+        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(generateURL(String.format("rest/%s/%s",
+                OfferDevRest.PATH,
+                OfferDevRest.RANDOM_OFFER_INCOGNITO_METHOD)));
+        httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
+                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("project1", ""),
+                "UTF-8",
+                false));
+        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
+        Assert.assertEquals(Response.SC_OK,
+                httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
+        HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
+        restResponse = IOUtils.toString(responseEntity.getContent(),
                 Charsets.UTF_8);
         Assert.assertEquals("0",
                 restResponse);
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,K,g,e,?]? e
```

I removed the `+` and `-` from the lines I don't want to add, but the patch doesn't apply cleanly. I assume I have to change the line/offset numbers as well, but how?

In some use cases one could use `git difftool` as a workaround, but that's not part of my question.

I'd be interested in a comment whether it would make sense to suggest support for multiple splits, i.e. splits of splits, to the `git` developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When editing the patch, it isn't a matter of adding or removing the + and -, you need to create a viable patch.

This is detailed in the documentation for [git add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_editing_patches), but the TL;DR version is:

- if you want to keep a deleted line, replace the - with a space
- if you don't want to add a line, remove the entire line.

Comment: I removed the - instead of replacing it with a space.